# Converting shapefile to .grd file?

Tags: arcmap, file-formats, esri-grid-format

I am new in ArcMap while using R Crisis software.

I need to convert a shapefile into a `.grd` file.

I read back the previous questions and answer and tried to execute and pop up that it was successfully saved as `.grd`.

But why it does not appear as `.grd` file, all files are in type `.adf`?

Comment: The `*.adf` files that you have created are likely to be the Esri Grid Format?  How precisely did you create them?

Comment: I go to conversion tool -> point to raster -> export -> choose grid file. But then i dont know the .grd file didnt appear in the file location, only the .adf file.